# Do the java packages differ from the concept of directory or folder? if yes how?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, package

I have a created a class by writing code as:

```
pacakge packtst;
public class Class1
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    System.out.print("This is class1");
  }
}
```

Then i compiled the program by

```
javac -d . Class1.java
```

It created a subdirectory in my current directory, named packtst. Then I went into the packtst deirectory. Within it i made another class as:

```
public class Class2
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    System.out.print("this is class2");
  }
}
```

And compiled it in the packtst directory by

```
javac Class2.java
```

So, now in the package packtst i have two class file Class1.class and Class2.class
Now I try to run Class1 from outside of the directory by

```
java packtst.Class1
```

It ran well. But then I tried to run Class2 from the same directory:

```
java packtst.Class2
```

It said `couldn't find or load main class packtst.Class2`

Why?

Comment: It's because your `Class2` doesn't have a `package` reference in it.

Comment: But why it needs a package reference its already in the package packtst. I am new to java. If you could help me understand this.

Comment: It is not in the package packtst. It's in the root, default package. And you chose the root of your package tree to be the current directory. You just created two separate package trees, and the root of the second is in a directory used for a branch of the first one. Don't do that. Either create two separate projects, with sources and classes of both projects in a completely separate location, or use a single project, and always use the same root directory for your sources, and the same root directory for your classes.

Comment: Its in dir packtst which is package for Class1, for Class2 there is package define and its gets compiled to same dir where it resides.

Comment: It might be located in the `packtst` folder and you will be able to run it by using `java Class2` but to be able to run it as `java packtst.Class2` it will need to have a reference to the package name. There is also a typo in your `Class1` where it says `pacakge` instead of `package`. Anyway, we never spent much time on `packages` at school but it allows you to create some structure in your project, you could create a package named `interfaces` to store your Interfaces etc. Read detailed explanation [on tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_packages.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a created a class by writing code as:

```
pacakge packtst;
public class Class1
```

> Then i compiled the program by

```
javac -d . Class1.java
```

That was your first two mistakes. The .java file should have been in the `packtst` directory, relative to where you started, and you should have compiled it via:

```
javac packtst/Class1.java
```

> Then I went into the packtst deirectory.

That was your second mistake. You should have stayed where you were.

> Within it i made another class as:

```
public class Class2
```

That was your third mistake. As `Class2` doesn't have a `package` statement, it should be in the directory that you started in.

> And compiled it in the packtst directory by

```
javac Class2.java
```

That was your fourth mistake. The `javac` command line is correct but it should have been issued from the directory you started in, i.e. the one that *contains* the `packtst` directory.

> So, now in the package packtst i have two class file Class1.class and Class2.class

That was your fifth mistake. Your directories from where you started should now contain:

```
packtest/Class1.class
Class2.class
```

> Now I try to run Class1 from outside of the directory by

```
java packtst.Class1
```

> It ran well.

So you must have now been in the directory you started in.

> But then I tried to run Class2 from the same directory:

```
java packtst.Class2
```

That was your sixth mistake. `Class2` isn't *in* the `packtst` *package*, because its source code doesn't contain such a `package` statement. The command should have been:

```
java Class2
```

> It said couldn't find or load main class `packtst.Class2`

Correct.

> Why?

Because *there is no such class.* The fully qualified name of `Class2` including all its declared packages, is `Class2`.

Answer (score 0):

In java, it is not enforced to have the same directory structure as your package structure referenced in that class. Since you are using the '-d' option to compile your code, the compiler will create a directory structure similar to the package structure to put the compiled class.
In the case of Class2, since you did not define any package reference for it, "packtst.Class2" will not exist.

Directory structure is a best-practice (to reflect the package structure in the source directory structure) and not something enforced by java compiler.

Also, package structure is the structure in which all your compiled classes would be present in the jar (or your complete project)

Answer (score 0):

> It said couldn't find or load main class packtst.Class2

because `Class2` does not have a / belong to a package name `packtst` 
Even the compiled class file is located in `packtst` the full qualified name of the class is `Class2` (the full qualified name of `Class1` is `packtst.Class1`). The package name is part of the (source) and the compiled class file.

That the package structure and the filesystem structure match is only a convention the java jvm and the java compilers use.

If the classes are stored on windows or *nix filesystems there is the convention that you must store a Java class in a directory with a relative directory path that matches the package name for that class.

Java Packages are an abstract construct. They help to organise the Applications into a set of packages. Each package has it's own set of names for the types (Classes, Interfaces,...) in the package, which helps to prevent naming conflicts.

The JLS (Java Language specification) only says about the package structure that it is hierarchical but also that you don't have to store java classes on an hierarchical filesystem you can also store them in a database.

[JLS Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html):

> The naming structure for packages is hierarchical (§7.1). The members
>   of a package are class and interface types (§7.6), which are declared
>   in compilation units of the package, and subpackages, which may
>   contain compilation units and subpackages of their own.
>
> A package can be stored in a file system or in a database (§7.2).
>   Packages that are stored in a file system may have certain constraints
>   on the organization of their compilation units to allow a simple
>   implementation to find classes easily.

If the classes are stored in a (hierarchical) file system which is similar to what you find on most PC and UNIX® systems, then the package name relates to the directory structure in which the class resides. This is how the actual java compilers, jvms / class loaders on Windows and *NIX work.

There is a article on the IBM Knowledge Base ([Java classes, packages, and directories](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/rzaha/clpckdir.htm)) which describes the relationship.